# Apex code mail is not sending

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service

i have tried out with the following code - am getting an exception of daily allowance of mail send,but actually none of the mails are send.whats the issue in this code??

```
public static void SendMailMethod(MailParameter [] mailParameters)
{      
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> myListofMails = NEW List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{};
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    if(MailParameters[0].ConDocIDs != Null)
    {
        List<ContentVersion> Contentversionlist = [select id,VersionData,PathOnClient,ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId IN:MailParameters[0].ConDocIDs];

        for (ContentVersion document: Contentversionlist)
        {
            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            attachment.setBody(document.VersionData); 
            attachment.setFileName(document.PathOnClient);
            attachments.add(attachment);
        }
        semail.setFileAttachments(attachments);
    }

    semail.setSubject(MailParameters[0].tosub);
    semail.setToAddresses(MailParameters[0].sendTo);
    if(MailParameters[0].bccAddresses != Null)
    {
        semail.setBccAddresses(MailParameters[0].bccAddresses);
    }
    if(MailParameters[0].ccAddresses!= Null)
    {
        semail.setCcAddresses(MailParameters[0].ccAddresses);
    }
    system.debug(semail);
    semail.setHtmlBody(MailParameters[0].messageBody); 
    myListofMails.add(semail);            
    System.debug('myListofMails'+ myListofMails.size());
    if(myListofMails.size()>0) 
    {
        try {
            Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(myListofMails.size());
            //if(!Test.isRunningTest())
              Messaging.sendEmail(myListofMails);
            System.debug('Your done! Mail sent successfully');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('You have used up your daily allowance of mails');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a sandbox? Sandboxes have email deliverability switched off by default so that you don't accidentally email your users. Search in setup for "Deliverability" and check that it's not set to "No access"